# Data serialization/deserialization to/from file

Tags: c#, file, serialization, deserialization

I am serializing/deserializing data using this:

```
        public static T ReadFile<T>(string path, string fileName, SaveFormat saveFormat)
    {
        fileName = fileName.CaseInsensitiveContains(".") ? fileName : fileName + "." + saveFormat.ToString();

        FullFileName = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        if (!File.Exists(FullFileName))
        {
            Debug.Print(FullFileName + " does not exist...");
            return default;
        }
        switch (saveFormat)
        {
            case SaveFormat.BIN:
                return ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(FullFileName);

            case SaveFormat.JSON:
                return ReadFromJsonFile<T>(FullFileName);

            case SaveFormat.XML:
                return ReadFromXmlFile<T>(FullFileName);
            default:
                return default;
        }
    }
```

usage examples:

```
DataEx1 = FileOps.ReadFile<MyCustomClass>(folderName, fileName, saveFormat);

DataEx2 = FileOps.ReadFile<Float[][]>(folderName, fileName, saveFormat);
```

It's working but I would prefer to use it as an extension method and not have to specify the data type as I will always be declaring the variable before, is it possible?

```
        float[][] data;
        data.ReadFromFile(folderName, fileName, saveFormat);
```

I tried :

```
        public static T LoadFromFile1<T>(this T data, string path, string fileName, FileOps.SaveFormat saveformat = FileOps.SaveFormat.JSON)
    {
        return FileOps.ReadFile<T>(path, fileName, saveformat);
    }
return FileOps.ReadFile <typeof(data)> (path, fileName, saveformat);
return FileOps.ReadFile <data.GetType()> (path, fileName, saveformat);
```

but none of those work, is it even possible or should I just stop wasting time on this and specify the data type?

Comment: I'd just use generics. It's not really more verbose/less readable anyways, plus with the way you're trying to do it you just kind of open yourself up to unassigned variable access errors if you forget to call `ReadFromFile` or you access the typed variable before it's been instantiated with `ReadFromFile`.

Comment: For `LoadFromFile1` there is no logic to use extension method. You need an object you call this function. But it doesn't consume an object, it produces the object. So you can have your `WriteTofile` method as extension but not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it even possible

Sort of.  This works:

```
float[][] data = null;
data = data.ReadFromFile( . . .);
```

> should I just stop wasting time on this and specify the data type?

Yes.  If you specify the variable like this you only have to type the type name once.

```
var data = FileOps.ReadFromFile<float[][]>(folderName, fileName, saveFormat);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, and you are right, there is not mutch to gain from it.